# WKWebView horizontal scrolling on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I've got a simple WKWebView and load a simple HTML-document into it.
The problem is: if the document has less content than the size of the WebView (e.g. only 5 lines of text) - WebView becomes scrollable not only vertical, but also horizontal. If I add enough text and it doesn't fit into the WebView - everything gets fine, only vertical scroll works.
This problem is observed **only on the iPad** and **only in landscape orientation**.
[image: Sample document...]
[image: And it scrolls horizontally :(]

Answer (score 0):

If you add this in the head section of your html, it should stop the horizontal scrolling

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
</head>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this solution. It works perfectly in landscape orientation, but totally ruins the size of content in portrait orientation. Text becomes much larger, both on iPhones and iPads. Is there an analog for this meta-tag in CSS so I could apply it only for landscape orientation?

Comment: Try messing with the initial-scale value

Answer (score 0):

Try adding - `shrink-to-fit=no` - like this -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```